# iMac with core i5 not works brightness

Tags: 12.04, brightness, mac

I have an iMac 2012 with core i5 but the brightness control doesn't work. The brightness works when the screen saver is activated but deosn't work with the <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> buttons. Now i'm working with an Ubuntu 12.04, How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Because that feature is a hardware related feature you can map the keys for brightness UP and DOWN. I do not remember of the right article right now, but search for mapping keys, and you can make your keys change brightness. Probably you will have to edit a file. There is already a post about that. Sorry for no solution right now, but it is possible to solve it. ;)